# How to mount different metadata templates for different devices of the same layer structure of Apache IoTDB?

Tags: time-series, apache-iotdb, iotdb

If there are multiple metadata templates under the `root.db` layer of Apache IoTDB data structure, then if I need to mount these templates to different devices for this layer, how does the devices know which metadata template it should be mounted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you need to classify the devices when modeling in Apache IoTDB. For example, there are three templates, `t1`, `t2`, `t3`, and the devices are divided into three categories: `device_class_A`, `device_class_B`, `device_class_C`. Then, you can mount different templates to different kinds of devices by `set schema template t1 to root.db.device_class_A`, `set schema template t2 to root.db.device_class_B`, `set schema template t3 to root.db.device_class_C`. Also, for this logic to be achieved, you need to upgrade to the latest 1.2.2 version of IoTDB.